# Three.js disable lighting

Tags: javascript, three.js, lighting

I want to disable lighting entirely in three.js, and render a 3D object.  Currently, since lighting is active in some form, the object appears completely black.  I have no calls to any sort of lighting currently in my program, and I have been unable to find a solution with searching.

[image]

Edit: Code

```
var white = 0xFFFFFF;

var facemat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: white, opacity: 1.0, shading: THREE.FlatShading } );

vrmlLoader.addEventListener('load', function ( event ) {
    var object = event.content;
    object.material = facemat;
    scene.add(object);
});

vrmlLoader.load("ship.wrl");
```

My questions for this particular post have mostly been answered.  If I am to ask more I will drive this post off topic.

Comment: What do you imagine the end result would look like?

Comment: @Nikola Dimitroff A completely white un-shaded model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shading / lighting take care of drawing an object in such a way that you can *perceive its depth*. In your example picture, shading is disabled - there is no depth, the object is the same everywhere - you cannot differentiate parts of it.

Now, it should be pretty obvious that you can't draw stuff without colour - just like you can't draw on a piece of paper without pencils or any other tool. What you are seeing is simply your object drawn with black colour. What you want to see is your object drawn in white, which is almost the same but if you do that currently, you'll see nothing since your background is white!

Anyway, after those clarifications, here is a how-to:

1. Change the background colour of your renderer to white:

   `renderer.setClearColor(0, 1)`
2. Change the colour of your object by changing its material:

   `object.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(0xFFFFFF)`

Comment: I have tested your ideas and they seem to indicate that lighting is somehow enabled within three.js.  Though I have the material set to solid white, and the clear color set to black, the model still shows up as solid black.

Comment: Sorry, for misleading you, I believe you are right. However, you can now bring your lighting back, since `THREE.MeshBasicMaterial` provides your desired effect - it won't render any lines and you'll see no depth perception. 

You can actually test that in the [three.js editor](http://threejs.org/editor). Import a mesh from the `File` menu, select it, then from the right pane choose Material -> MeshBasicMaterial.

Comment: Strangely enough, in your three.js editor, my model works and renders properly.  It seems to just not render in my code.  I will post the amount I'm having trouble with in the main post.  My model is still rendering black.

Comment: After loading the model, do all faces have a material index of 0?
`object.geometry.faces.forEach(function (face) { console.log(face.materialIndex) })` should print a gazillion of zeros and nothing else. If not, you need to set it manually (`face.materialIndex = 0;`)